# NotaryFlow$Client is not registered Error in Corda Obligation Code

Tags: corda

I am doing some tests in a Linux server environment with Corda Enterprise 3.1 and the Obligation sample code from R3. When I try to execute a flow, I get an exception from the Notary in the log of the node initiating the flow. I have pasted log entries in below. All the nodes are being recognized as valid, but the message seems to say that the client for the notary flow is not registered. Where would I register it? What would I register?

The code being executed is:

```
val flowHandle = service.proxy.startFlowDynamic(
                IssueObligation.Initiator::class.java,
                issueAmount,
                lenderIdentity,
                true
        )
```

The logs show this stack trace:

```
[INFO ] 2018-09-27T23:07:51,522Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPChannelHandler.invoke - Handshake completed with subject: O=Notary, L=London, C=GB {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, localCert=O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US, remoteAddress=xxxxx:10102, remoteCert=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2018-09-27T23:07:51,524Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] bridging.AMQPBridgeManager$AMQPBridge.invoke - Bridge Connected {bridgeName=internal.peers.DLCYA2tcXLrUnF9bkTMwouBuHooVn416Dc8Gk8JBaze4Gk -> xxxxx:10102, legalNames=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, maxMessageSize=10485760, queueName=internal.peers.DLCYA2tcXLrUnF9bkTMwouBuHooVn416Dc8Gk8JBaze4Gk, target=xxxxx:10102}
[INFO ] 2018-09-27T23:07:51,530Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] engine.ConnectionStateMachine.invoke - Connection local open org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ConnectionImpl@2e08c638 {localLegalName=O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US, remoteLegalName=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, serverMode=false}
[INFO ] 2018-09-27T23:07:56,988Z [flow-worker] corda.flow.run - Flow threw exception... sending to flow hospital {actor_id=user1, actor_owningIdentity=O=PartyB, L=New York, C=US, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10396171, flow-id=af75a3d3-402c-45e2-89af-48dce5b11998, invocation_id=1399fb77-c4ed-4a09-972b-76c6ffb09bdc, invocation_timestamp=2018-09-27T23:07:49.588Z, session_id=d3c04d4a-f722-4cbd-95ec-dd2f744a36cd, session_timestamp=2018-09-27T23:05:30.595Z, thread-id=201, tx_id=2D94EABC8EBE902AC24A64A2562C293A1FB26747D0A04821A497FD333944F220}
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: class net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client is not registered
            at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:166) ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:396) ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.sendAndReceiveWithRetry$core(FlowLogic.kt:245) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.sendAndReceiveNonValidating(NotaryFlow.kt:140) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.notarise(NotaryFlow.kt:94) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:65) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
            at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:45) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you update the post to include the logs on the notary side? Are all the nodes Corda Ent 3.1 nodes, and is the CorDapp also compiled against Corda Ent 3.1?

Comment: All the nodes are running under Corda Enterprise 3.1 and the "Yo" CorDapp works successfully, but is not dependent on notary signing anyway. In the configuration of the notary, I made it validating = false. Does that make any difference? I am adding the notary log below which also shows this error.

Comment: [WARN ] 2018-09-27T23:07:52,315Z [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] statemachine.MultiThreadedStateMachineManager.onSessionInit - Exception while creating initiated flow {}
net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SessionRejectException: class net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client is not registered
 at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.MultiThreadedStateMachineManager.getInitiatedFlowFactory(MultiThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:510) ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?]

Comment: I think I am getting closer to solving the problem. I went back and looked at the node.conf for the notary node and realized that I had not made an entry identifying it as a notary. I added: "notary" {  "validating" : true } which got me past that error. I now get the error: net.corda.core.transactions.FilteredTransaction cannot be cast to net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction. Should I make the notary validating = false?

Comment: Changing validating = false for the notary got obligation to work. Now I just have issues with the vault queries to show what is recorded. This was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the notary not being configured as such. As a result, it did not have a responder flow for `NotaryFlow$Client` installed.

The follow-up error you received, `net.corda.core.transactions.FilteredTransaction cannot be cast to net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.`, indicates that the node requesting notarisation incorrectly identified the notary as non-validating rather than validating. As a result, it sent the wrong transaction type.